# How can I resolve a component that has been registered with a keyed filter argument in the constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a concrete class implementation of my service interface like the following:

```
public class MyService:IService {
     public MyService([KeyFilter("sampleone")] IRepository repoToUse) {
           _repoToUse = repoToUse;
     }

     // rest of code
}
```

I am registering the service as:

```
builder.Register(ctx => new CustomRepo()).Keyed<IRepository>("sampleone");
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().AsSelf().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

In my controller, I am using the lifetime scope to resolve the services.

```
public class MyTestController:ApiController{
    public MyTestController(ILifteTimeScope scope) {
         var testone = scope.Resolve(typeof(IService));
         var testtwo = scope.Resolve(typeof(MyService));
    }
}
```

So I'm resolving these services and I am able to resolve "testone" properly but when the application tries to resolve "testtwo", it throws an error: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException. It essentially states that I am unable to resolve the IRepository.

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I derped and this is working.

I registered the type later on during the process as self() but without attribute filtering so it overwrote the earlier registrations.

e.g.

```
// later on in the execution path.
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IServiceTwo>.AsSelf();
```